# Migrating a Guice-based project to Dagger

Tags: java, guice, dagger-2

I have a Guice based project using vanilla Guice;
no Assisted-Inject, no AOP, no extra plugin extending Guice, etc.
To run it more easily on Android, Dagger seems like a better solution.
Every class has a dependency and a constructor with `@Inject` annotation.
No field or method injection is used.

The modules are quite simple (making Guice an overkill) and mostly contain bindings like the following:

```
class SomethingModule extends AbstractModule {

  protected void configure() {
    Bind(Handler.class)
      .annotatedWith(Names.named("something"))
      .to(SomeImplementation.class);
    }
  }

}
```

And later used like the following:

```
Injector inj = Guice.createInjector(new SomethingModule());
... = inj.getInstance(SampleInterface.class);
// and rest of the code.
```

Unfortunately,
I can not get my head around [Daggers terminology](http://google.github.io/dagger/users-guide.html).
Can you guide me with a direct translation / transformation of a Guice module to a Dagger module?

Dagger has:

- Dagger's Components.
- Dagger's Modules.
- `@Provides`
- `@Inject`

Guice has:

- `@Inject`
- `@Named` (or any custom annotation, if implemented correctly).
- Our modules extending `AbstractModule`.
- `@Provides` in the modules.
- Guice `Injector` created from modules.

How do these relate?

*Update:* In addition to the nice answer by EpicPandaForce, [these slides](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1fby5VeGU9CN8zjw4lAb2QPPsKRxx6mSwCe9q7ECNSJQ/pub?start=false&loop=false&delayms=3000) can help too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Bind(Handler.class)
.annotatedWith(Names.named("something"))
.to(SomeImplementation.class);
```

Would translate to

```
@Module
public class SomethingModule {
    @Provides
    @Named("something")
    //scope if needed
    public Handler handler() {
        return new SomeImplementation();
    }
}
```

Which would be bound to an "`Injector`" (component):

```
@Component(modules={SomethingModule.class})
//scope if needed
public interface SomethingComponent {
    @Named("something")
    Handler handler();

    void inject(ThatThingy thatThingy);
}
```

Which is an "injector" that you have to create with the APT-generated builder:

```
SomethingComponent somethingComponent = DaggerSomethingComponent.builder()
                                           .somethingModule(new SomethingModule()) //can be omitted, has no params
                                           .build();
somethingComponent.inject(thatThingy);
```

Where that thingy has

```
public class ThatThingy {
    @Inject
    @Named("something")
    Handler handler;
}
```

Components typically exist **per scope**, so for example `@ApplicationScope` has *one* "injector" (component). Scoping can be achieved with subcomponents and component dependencies.

Important fact, a component has provision methods (which are the dependencies that are inherited to subscoped components if you use component dependencies), and `void inject(X x);` formatted methods. This is required for field injection **per concrete type**. A base class for example can only inject *itself*, and **not** its subclasses. You can however write a method called `protected abstract void injectThis()` which would call the  `.inject(this)` on the subclass as well.

As I haven't really used Guice, I'm not sure if I missed out on anything. I think I forgot constructor injection, which is an issue because while Dagger does support it, it cannot be reconfigured. For reconfiguration, you have to use modules, and do the injection in the constructors yourself.

```
@Module(includes={ThoseModule.class, TheseModule.class})
public abstract class SomethingModule {
    @Binds
    abstract Whatever whatever(WhateverImpl impl);
}

@Singleton
public class WhateverImpl implements Whatever {
    Those those;
    These these;

    @Inject
    public Whatever(Those those, These these) {
        this.those = those;
        this.these = these;
    }
}

@Component(modules={SomethingModule.class})
@Singleton
public interface SomethingComponent {
    These these();
    Those those();
    Whatever whatever();
}
```

Comment: Nitpick: a closer Dagger equivalent of `bind(X.class).to(Y.class)` is `@Provides X provideX(Y y) { return y; }`

Comment: @TavianBarnes but where would the module obtain an instance of `Y`? You have to create it somewhere.

Comment: If `Y` has an `@Inject` constructor, it will be called automatically